# Is it possible to create a html page that will send email using gem 'mail' in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Like a full working html page with text fields,button etc which will then use the gem mail to send the email.

Is it possible to do that ?

I know it usually works with php etc but was wondering if its possible with ruby(only ruby not ROR).

`

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>
 <body>



 Your email:<br>
 <input type="text" name="mymail"><br>

 Your password:<br>
 <input type="text" name="password"><br>

 To:<br>
 <input type="text" name="to"><br>

 Subject:<br>
 <input type="text" name="subject"><br>

 Message:<br>
 <input type="text" name="message" size="50"><br><br> 

<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

`

Comment: Yes, it's possible. How do you think rails works? It's only ruby.

Comment: It's not as simple in the beginning with Ruby, because the webserver does not execute Ruby directly like mod_php does. You need to look up how to write a Ruby CGI script (google it), or look at lightweight frameworks like Sinatra if you do not want to run a full Rails stack. Ruby is not PHP, and web pages served by Ruby are usually run as applications and not directly as simple scripts as you do with PHP. If you want script-like functionality then look into Ruby with CGI. Otherwise search for Ruby and microframeworks to get some alternatives to Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use the email gem for sending emails, although there is a simpler solution. It is called Ruby SMTP, included as a part of the ruby library. This is how to send one email given input:

```
require 'net/smtp'

message = <<MESSAGE_END
From: Private Person <me@fromdomain.com>
To: A Test User <test@todomain.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html
Subject: SMTP e-mail test

This is an e-mail message to be sent in HTML format

<b>This is HTML message.</b>
<h1>This is headline.</h1>
MESSAGE_END

Net::SMTP.start('localhost') do |smtp|
  smtp.send_message message, 'me@fromdomain.com', 
                             'test@todomain.com'
end
```

All the data for the email would be extracted from variables. These variables would be set equal to the data input your user gives. More info here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_sending_email.htm

Comment: Thanks for your answer. so how would i create a html page that would read the ruby script to send the email as soon as i click send button

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Have you been following my suggestions, and googling how to solve it? I've proposed part of the answer, but Stackoverflow is mainly for error resolution. @noname

Comment: I have simple html page as you can see above i added,i want it to read the script to send the email , i get your answer but how do i make it read from this html page that i made ..thats where i get confused

Comment: @noname you'll need to change the ending of your HTML file to "(pagename).html.erb" so you can include the ruby above in the file using <%= (ruby in here) %>. Rails makes data manipulation much easier, but it is do-able with ruby alone. I'd google solutions for variables between HTML and Ruby at this point, or ask a new question on Stackoverflow. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the information :) really appreciate it

Comment: Sure thing. Any time